# Casting unsigned int to unsigned short int with bit operator

Tags: c, casting

I would like to cast unsigned int (32bit) A to unsigned short int (16bit) B in a following way:

- if A <= 2^16-1 then B=A
- if A >  2^16-1 then B=2^16-1

In other words to cast A but if it is > of maximum allowed value for 16bit to set it as max value.

How can this be achieved with bit operations or other **non branching** method?

Comment: Did you mean "...then B=2^16-1"?

Comment: Did you mean B=2^16-1 if A > 2^16-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find minimum of two integers without branching:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

> On some rare machines where branching
>   is very expensive and no condition
>   move instructions exist, the above
>   expression might be faster than the
>   obvious approach, r = (x < y) ? x : y,
>   even though it involves two more
>   instructions. (Typically, the obvious
>   approach is best, though.)

Just to kick things off, here's a brain-dead benchmark. I'm trying to get a 50/50 mix of large and small values "at random":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t total = 0;
    uint32_t n = 27465;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000*1000*500; ++i) {
        n *= 30029; // worst PRNG in the world
        uint32_t a = n & 0x1ffff;
        #ifdef EMPTY
            uint16_t b = a; // gives the wrong total, of course.
        #endif
        #ifdef NORMAL
            uint16_t b = (a > 0xffff) ? 0xffff : a;
        #endif
        #ifdef RUSLIK
            uint16_t b = (-(a >> 16) >> 16) | a;
        #endif
        #ifdef BITHACK
            uint16_t b = a ^ ((0xffff ^ a) & -(0xffff < a));
        #endif
        total += b;
    }
    std::cout << total << "\n";
}
```

On my compiler (gcc 4.3.4 on cygwin with -O3), `NORMAL` wins, followed by `RUSLIK`, then `BITHACK`, respectively 0.3, 0.5 and 0.9 seconds slower than the empty loop. Really this benchmark means nothing, I haven't even checked the emitted code to see whether the compiler's smart enough to outwit me somewhere. But I like ruslik's anyway.

Comment: I was looking a minute ago exactly at this but could not figure out how this apply to operands of different type.

Comment: That has a `<` in it, which many compilers (but not modern gcc) would compile to a branch..

Comment: @Ross: I was thinking, take the minimum in 32-bit, then convert to 16-bit. @R..: true, but hopefully not compilers for architectures on which branching is so slow that it's worth avoiding in a case like this. For that matter, the obvious approach won't branch on architectures with conditional instructions (ARM), if the compiler's any good at all.

Comment: OK, It seems that obvious solution r = (x < y) ? x : y is better in most cases.

Comment: @Ross: well, in the opinion of Anderson. As you can see from the notes to many of the twiddling hacks, he's not error-free. But it does suggest that there's no clear-cut way that's "expected" to be faster on most common implementations, or someone would have submitted it :-)

Comment: Branching is bad, because of pipeline control hazard . See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Control_hazards_%2e28branch_hazards%2e29

Comment: @Vlad: yeah, but slamming in buckets of extra instructions to avoid branching is also bad. It's not really possible to generalize which is worse.

Comment: @Steve: Taking into account the typical length of the processor pipeline, I would tend to prefer extra 5-10 instructions to one branch. This however needs strict profiling.

Comment: @Vlad: and of course it's difficult to profile in isolation on a modern CPU, because the blighter might be predicting the branch more accurately than you think, so you don't know whether your test loop is in any way comparable to realistic use. And there may not actually be a pipeline stall anyway even with the branch in this case, and so on until you just give up and profile the whole app.

Comment: @Steve I think normal wins because of `CMOVE`.

Comment: @ruslik: indeed, and the answer to the question, "how do I do this without branching" is, on many compilers and architectures, `b = (a > 0xffff) ? 0xffff : a;`. The reason I like yours is because at least superficially, it doesn't look like it would ever branch on any sensible implementation unless because of some clever optimization. So it's a candidate to leave lying around in the "portability" section of an app that tends to bottleneck on this operation, as the thing to test against NORMAL when porting to a new platform, before writing something totally platform-specific (perhaps in asm).

Answer (score 5):

It will work for unsigned values:

```
b = -!!(a >> 16) | a;
```

or, something similar:

```
static inline unsigned short int fn(unsigned int a){
    return (-(a >> 16) >> 16) | a;
};
```

Comment: I like you solution too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) With an intrinsic on a CPU that natively does this sort of convertion.

2) You're probably not going to like this, but:

```
c = a >> 16; /* previously declared as a short */
/* Saturate 'c' with 1s if there are any 1s, by first propagating
1s rightward, then leftward. */
c |= c >> 8;
c |= c >> 4;
c |= c >> 2;
c |= c >> 1;
c |= c << 1;
c |= c << 2;
c |= c << 4;
c |= c << 8;
b = a | c; /* implicit truncation */
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the phrase "non-branching method" doesn't technically make sense when discussing C code; the optimizer may find ways to remove branches from "branchy" C code, and conversely would be entirely within its rights to replace your clever non-branching code with a branch just to spite you (or because some heuristic said it would be faster).

That aside, the simple expression:

```
uint16_t b = a > UINT16_MAX ? UINT16_MAX : a;
```

despite "having a branch", will be compiled to some sort of (branch-free) conditional move (or possible just a saturate) by many compilers on many systems (I just tried three different compilers for ARM and Intel, and all generated a conditional move).

I would use that simple, readable expression.  If and only if your compiler isn't smart enough to optimize it (or your target architecture doesn't have conditional moves), and if you have benchmark data that shows this to be a bottleneck for your program, then I would (a) find a better compiler and (b) file a bug against your compiler and *only then* look for clever hacks.

If you're really, truly devoted to being too clever by half, then **ruslik**'s second suggestion is actually quite beautiful (much nicer than a generic min/max).